# Add two arrays without using for. Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have these two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 10, 20])
b = np.array([20, 30, 40, 50])
```

I´d like to add both in the following way while avoiding slow Python `for` loops:

```
c = array([20, 30, 40, 50, 30, 40, 50, 60, 40, 50, 60, 70])
```

It means, for the first element of "a" add all the elements of b,then for the second element and so on.

I know it seems quite easy, but for huge arrays Python loops are too slow.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `for` loops?

Comment: what are your arrays? numpy, array.array ?

Comment: do `for`'s in list comprehensions count? ;)

Comment: there is no such thing as 'array' in Python. You have tuples or lists or sets.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 the problem is that when the vector is huge it takes longer than other way, for example:
   for i in range len(a):
     a[i]-b[:]
I have to use only a for instead of two, but I want no for

Comment: and btw the arrays have been created with np.linspace or np.zeros(())

Comment: @FernandoBastosGarcía, you should really add that you have numpy arrays and you want to avoid slow python loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
In [17]: a = np.array([0, 10, 20])

In [18]: b = np.array([20, 30, 40, 50])  

In [19]: (a.reshape(-1, 1) + b).ravel()
Out[19]: array([20, 30, 40, 50, 30, 40, 50, 60, 40, 50, 60, 70])
```

Here are the details.

`a.reshape(-1, 1)` converts `a` to an array with shape (3, 1):

```
In [20]: a.reshape(-1, 1)
Out[20]: 
array([[ 0],
       [10],
       [20]])
```

When `b` is added to that, [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) applies, which in effect does an "outer sum" (i.e. adds all the pairwise combinations), forming an array with shape (3, 4):

```
In [21]: a.reshape(-1, 1) + b
Out[21]: 
array([[20, 30, 40, 50],
       [30, 40, 50, 60],
       [40, 50, 60, 70]])
```

The [`ravel()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) flattens the result into a one-dimensional array:

```
In [22]: (a.reshape(-1, 1) + b).ravel()
Out[22]: array([20, 30, 40, 50, 30, 40, 50, 60, 40, 50, 60, 70])
```

See @HYRY's answer for an even more concise version.

Answer (score 1):

you can use outer method of ufunc:

```
np.add.outer(a, b).ravel()
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible and only memory not time intensive solution is using `np.repeat` and `np.resize` to repeat and resize the arrays a and b to the size of the resulting shape first and then simply add those two arrays.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 10, 20])
b = np.array([20, 30, 40, 50])

def extend_and_add(a, b):
    return np.repeat(a, len(b)) + np.resize(b, len(a)*len(b))
```

So `extend_and_add(a, b)` returns:

```
extend_and_add(a, b)
> array([20, 30, 40, 50, 30, 40, 50, 60, 40, 50, 60, 70])
```

---

**Explanation:**

Basically `np.repeat(a, len(b))` repeats:

```
a
> array([ 0, 10, 20])
```

to

```
np.repeat(a, len(b))
> array([ 0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20])
```

after this you need the second array resized with `np.resize`:

```
b
> array([20, 30, 40, 50])
```

is resized to:

```
np.resize(b, len(a)*len(b))
> array([20, 30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

Now we can simply add the arrays:

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20])
+
array([20, 30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

returns:

```
array([20, 30, 40, 50, 30, 40, 50, 60, 40, 50, 60, 70])
```

Answer (score -2):

First you need to specify the array type, if you use a constructor like that. For instance for integers, use that:

```
a = array("i",[0, 10, 20])       # signed int type
b = array("i",[20, 30, 40, 50])
```

Them you might want to use while loops with counters, it is more complex than for, but avoids the for loop.

```
from array import array

a = array("i",[0, 10, 20])  # signed int

b = array("i",[20, 30, 40, 50]) 

c = array("i",[])

count1 = 0

while count1 < len(a):
   count2 = 0
   while count2 < len(b):
       c.append(a[count1]+b[count2])
       count2 += 1
   count1 += 1

print(c)
```

Comment: The OP is already using `numpy`; no need to switch to the other Python `array` module.